# Como pausar un audio y que se reproduzca otro en una misma app

Tags: android-studio

He combinado dos proyectos, una radio on line y un reproductor de música on line.
Pero al reproducir la radio y luego la música on line, suenan al mismo tiempo.
Necesito ayuda de como puedo hacer que al reproducir una, la otra se pause se detenga.
Estuve indagando sobre Managing Audio Focus pero no sé si es lo correcto o si me pueden dar un tip de usar el mismo servicio para los dos proyectos.
De antemano muchas gracias.
Este es código del MusicPLayActivity.java del codigo del reproductor de música 
on line.

```
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override 
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // check for already playing
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.pause();
                    // Changing button image to play button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);

                }
            }else{

                // Resume song
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.start();

                    // Changing button image to pause button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_paush);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Este es el código de la radio on line: FragmentRadio.java

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == buttonPlay) {

        if (urlToPlay != null) {
            startPlaying();

            buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buttonStopPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            AudioManager am = (AudioManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            int volume_level = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            if (volume_level < 1) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, getResources().getString(R.string.volume_low), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (counter == Config.INTERSTITIAL_COUNTER_NUMBER) {
                interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
                interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            interstitialAd.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                counter = 1;
            } else {
                counter++;
            }


        } else {
            Log.d("INFO", "The loading of urlToPlay should happen almost instantly, so this code should never be reached");
        }

    } else if (view == buttonStopPlay) {
        stopPlaying();

        buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonStopPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private void startPlaying() {

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    radioManager.startRadio(urlToPlay);
    radioManager.updateNotification(
            activity.getResources().getString(R.string.notification_title),
            activity.getResources().getString(R.string.notification_subtitle),
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    );
    updateButtons();
}

private void stopPlaying() {

    radioManager.stopRadio();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    updateButtons();
    if (runningOnOldConnection) {
        resetRadioManager();
    }
}
```

Este último usa la librería mobiwise https://github.com/mobiwiseco/RadioPlayerService

No sé si con estos datos es suficiente.
Gracias.

Comment: si no agregas lo que tienes, estas realizando una pregunta basada en opinones, no hablas de que clase usas es dificil dar una respuesta acertada.

Comment: @Jorgesys he editado mi pregunta. Gracias.